# Can I write a 16bit greyscale .PGM file? or should I make a .RAW?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, ascii

I wanted to know if Photoshop or Gimp would properly read an ASCII .PGM file with 16bit values.

I tried but it didn't work, however I don't see why it is impossible.

take a pgm file like this:

```
P2
3
3
65535
0
0
0
32767
32767
32767
65535
65535
65535
```

or a ppm file like this:

```
P5
3
3
65535
0
0
0
32767
32767
32767
65535
65535
65535
```

why it doesn't work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example (using Magic Number P2) is a completely valid image and works just fine for me using ACDSee, as well as a PGM parser I wrote in C# a few years ago. My best guess at this point is that Photoshop and/or Gimp did not properly implement the PGM standard.

Here is what your first example looks like to me (enlarged):

[image: pgm]

The second example you provided is the "Plain" PGM format which is even more obscure and probably not supported.

You might try saving the files in the binary version of the PGM format, as that version is fast and much more widely used - perhaps support will be better.

Coincidentally, there are much better image formats than PGM these days, even for strictly grayscale applications. Is there any particular reason you want to use this format?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually this 1st image works as well with me - at least its rendering -, on Gimp, not Photoshop. Strangely enough Photoshop recognises that it is a 16bit Greyscale image, but the rendering is wrong. Gimp opens it, but transformed to 8bit, which is a problem for me. The reason I use this format is that it is very easy to export from small python / C++ scripts that I write (I use it because I have very basic - let's say poor - knowledge of programming...)